# Unable to understand date function in PHP

Tags: php

Based on the definition given on [php.net](http://php.net) about function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), I tried to use it in the code like this:

```
echo"The date is :".date("l, d/m/Y, h:i:s a", time());
```

But the timestamp doesn't get printed. Why is this? I am unable to understand this part of the function.

Comment: working fine:- https://eval.in/731708

Comment: If you're just trying to output the timestamp, as per your question, simply use `time()`. See: https://eval.in/731715

Comment: Thanks Marc. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

To print timestamp just use `time()`

```
echo time();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem:
I had to written the code properly but since It was not displaying current date and time, I was confused. I set the time zone to Asia/Kolkata. Now its working fine. 
Thank you everyone for help.